# ImportError : image not found when I use Python library--pymrmr

Tags: python, openmp, llvm

- **pymrmr version - 0.1.8**
- **Python version -3.6**
- **OS - Mac OS 10.14.5**

I want to use a Python library ---**pymrmr**.
after installing, I get a ImportError when importing it:

```
import pymrmr
```

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymrmr.cpython-36m-darwin.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libiomp/lib/libiomp5.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymrmr.cpython-36m-darwin.so
>   Reason: image not found

I tried some solutions:

```
brew install libomp
```

and

```
brew install llvm
```

but none works for me.

and  I find that the category----`/usr/local/opt/libiomp/` does not exists

Only this directory exists ----- `/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib`

Is there something wrong here？

Hope everyone can give me ideas.

Thanks in advance!